# qtip hide tooltip by click button inside

Tags: javascript, meteor, qtip2

I have a button inside qtip tooltip which remove target object on click to it. But after remove target object(calendar event) tooltip stay visible. How to remove/hide tooltip also?
Below is qtip options and screenshot.

`var content = '<button class="btn btn-xs btn-default delCalendarEvent" id="' + event._id + '"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>';
element.qtip({
    show: {
        event: 'click',
        solo: true
    },
    hide: {
        event: 'click unfocus'
    },
    content: content,
    style: {
        classes: 'qtip-bootstrap'
    },
    position: {
        my: 'bottom center',
        at: 'top center',
        container: $('.fc')
    }
});`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try playing around with having the content be generated from a function, like this:

```
  $('a[title]').qtip({show: {
        event: 'click',
        solo: true
    },
    hide: {
        event: 'click unfocus'
    },
    content: function() { 
      var context = this.context;
      var btn = $('<button class="btn btn-xs btn-default delCalendarEvent" id="55">X</button>');
      btn.click(function () { 
        $(context).qtip().destroy();
        $(context).remove();
      })
      return btn;
    },
    style: {
        classes: 'qtip-bootstrap'
    },
    position: {
        my: 'bottom center',
        at: 'top center',
        container: $('.fc')
    }
  });
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tnmj7w1p/